# group dataframe or tibble without writing a loop

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to group values. I need to group all the distinct values in index into the least number of groups possible where the index column does not repeat within a group. I am trying to do this without a loop.

given:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   barcode  index                      
   <chr>    <chr>                      
 1 XPO21451 a
 2 XPO21546 a
 3 XPO21500 a
 4 XPO21454 b
 5 XPO21503 c
 6 XPO21457 c
 7 XPO21506 1
 8 XPO21460 1
 9 XPO21509 1
10 XPO21463 2
```

I need a result of

group 1

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   barcode  index  
   <chr>    <chr>                      
 1 XPO21451 a
 4 XPO21454 b
 5 XPO21503 c
 7 XPO21506 1
10 XPO21463 2
```

group 2

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   barcode  index  
   <chr>    <chr>                      
 2 XPO21546 a
 6 XPO21457 c
 8 XPO21460 1
```

group 3

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   barcode  index  
   barcode  index                      
   <chr>    <chr>                      
 3 XPO21500 a
 9 XPO21509 1
```

Any Idea on how I can do this without creating an explicit loop or apply on this dataset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a sequence by 'index' and then `split` the data by the 'grp' created

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(index) %>% 
    mutate(grp = row_number()) %>%
    split(.$grp)
```

---

or with `base R`, use `ave` to create the sequence and do the `split`

```
grp <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(index), index, FUN = seq_along))
split(df1, grp)
#$`1`
#    barcode index
#1  XPO21451     a
#4  XPO21454     b
#5  XPO21503     c
#7  XPO21506     1
#10 XPO21463     2

#$`2`
#   barcode index
#2 XPO21546     a
#6 XPO21457     c
#8 XPO21460     1

#$`3`
#   barcode index
#3 XPO21500     a
#9 XPO21509     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(barcode = c("XPO21451", "XPO21546", "XPO21500", 
 "XPO21454", "XPO21503", "XPO21457", "XPO21506", "XPO21460", "XPO21509", 
 "XPO21463"), index = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "1", "1", 
 "1", "2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
 "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thank you. this is exaclty what I needed. since my dataset is way more complex then what I sent and I needed to do this across multiple columns individually then split I used your tidyverse example above with a few group by and mutates then tidyr::unite() the columns and split based on that. Huge help! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not certain about tidyverse, but a simple solution for grouping in the way that you are looking for can be obtained by using data.table

```
dat <- data.table(dat)
dat[,group := seq.int(.N), by = index, on = index]
```

this adds a group column to the dataset, which one can then use to extract the various groups

```
dat[group == 3]
```

Alternatively if saving the group is for some reason not possible:

```
dat <- data.table(dat)
dat[,.(barcode, index, group = seq.int(.N)), by = index, on = index][group == 3]
```